# getparameter return null jsp when get time like 9:00

Tags: database, jsp

```
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn
            .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO discussion(section_id, weekday, room, mandatory, starttime,endtime) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("SECTION_ID")));
    pstmt.setString(2, request.getParameter("WEEKDAY"));
    pstmt.setString(3, request.getParameter("ROOM"));
    pstmt.setString(4, request.getParameter("MANDATORY"));

    String TIME_FORMAT = "HH:mm";
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT,
            Locale.getDefault());

    out.println("Items: " + request.getParameter("starttime"));
    out.println("Items: " + request.getParameter("WEEKDAY"));
    pstmt.setTime(5,
            new Time(timeFormat.parse(request.getParameter("starttime"))
                    .getTime()));
    pstmt.setTime(6,
            new Time(timeFormat.parse(request.getParameter("endtime"))
                    .getTime()));
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

I use `out.print` to test. find out that `getparameter` works not right. It can give me the weekday data but cannot give me starttime data. The database give starttime time type

Comment: did you have set these values in the html form that u r using in the getparameter method

Comment: also hope starttime is the name  and not the id in html

Comment: it would be better if u provide us wid d html file too..

Comment: CREATE TABLE discussion
(
  section_id integer NOT NULL,
  weekday character varying, -- monday, tuesday, wed.....
  room character varying,
  mandatory character varying,
  starttime time without time zone,
  endtime time without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT discussion_pkey PRIMARY KEY (section_id),
  CONSTRAINT discussion_section_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (section_id)
      REFERENCES section (section_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

Comment: there is no html file. just run discussion.jsp in eclipse.